# CSS to add some text at the end of the link

Tags: html, css

I have searched all over the internet but could not find a solution.

I need some CSS that will add some extra text at the end of the URL.
For example- www.google.com/search-url
I want something that automatically adds '/download' at the end of the url.

Update: If it is not possible through css, please share jquery/php code.

Comment: Please give a better example, you mean to the link text or the actual url. show with code example what you are trying to do.

Comment: Comes to mind: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_sel_after_style

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that what you're looking for is possible with CSS.
CSS is used to design your websites and improve the front-end of your site.
If you want to work more on the back-end and for example change strings(like your link) then you could use [PHP](http://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp).

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it in CSS.

CSS can change how the link is displayed - e.g. `a:after { content: ' (download)' }` will mean links are followed by a piece of text - but it can't alter the actual content of the HTML, in this case the href attribute which governs where the link actually points.

You will need to do this in JavaScript or server-side.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but you might want to use PHP or maybe jQuery

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an almost impossible thing to do with css but there is something you can try.
This is some code I've used lately to show the url of a link for print versions of the page.

```
a:after {
    content: " [Link: " attr(href) "]";
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

The part you can use is just a: after and the first line inside it. In your case it should be something like this:

```
a:after {
        content: "/download";
}
```

I'm not sure if it will be part of the clickable link but you never know.
I't would be a lot easier and more logical to do this with, JavaScript or PHP or ...

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do it in CSS is with `content: (text)` but it's actually better to do in HTML (or other language) in case you need to fix something.